# Mapping an image larger than screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using imgareaselect jQuery plugin to create mapping of an image.
When I select/map the image equal to size of screen, everything works fine.
But, when I need to map an image larger in height than screen, I cannot do so.

When I scroll down the page to map, the map area is shown somewhere else rather than original place.

I also attached a screenshot.

Original image at top position
[image]

But when I scroll down to map other area, as image is larger than screen height, it does not work.
[image]

This is a code which I use to map the area and get coordinates to store in DB

```
$('#body_img').imgAreaSelect(
{
    handles: true,
    show: true,
    parent: "img",
    onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) 
    {
          alert('Start: ' + selection.x1+','+selection.y1 + '; End: ' +     selection.x2+','+selection.y2);

      }
  });
```

Here, img is the image and "selection" has the coordinates of map.

I am using jquery's imgAreaSelect plugin.

Comment: actual code and name of the jQuery plugin you're using would be needed to give you an advice

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to modify `parent` property in your options - remove it or set some other div element? In your example code it seems that you're setting it to image tag.

[Plugin examples page](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) loads super-slowly as for me, so it's hard to test.

Comment: This plugin by default takes Parent: 'body'. I was just trying with 'img'. I will try other div as well.

Comment: Can it be due to some CSS positioning?